# Tool that imports C# source code into SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Am having trouble googling for this type of product which am sure is out there so wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Is there a  s/w tool that can import C# source code files into a SQL database and which then has a front end that allows a user to easily search for various things from that imported data - i.e: method names, types, etc

It would be a nice pet project to do in my own time but our team are looking for something out of the box and slick that is out there already - anyone know of any products?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you add more details on what you want to use this tool for (as opposed to how it's implemented), then you might get better help.

Comment: SO is not the place to get product recommendations (assuming a product for this even exists), and to help you implement such a solution there is little to none information in the question about what your first/biggest problem is, so you need to specify what you need help with.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness of the question - i was in a bit of a rush when i wrote it - Dai has supplied me with a sufficient answer to my query in any case,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use SQL Server (or any RDBMS for that matter) for this because source-code files are not an example of relational data.

Instead you would run each source file through a parser and extract symbol names (e.g. type names, member/field/variable names, etc) then index them using a system like Lucene.

Comment: Thanks Dai & i agree with what you say about the files not being example of relational data which makes sense if there is probably no product that exists out of the box for such a job.  Il look into trying this using Lucene.NET perhaps instead.